# Why does flutter crash when I try to open a previously created pdf?

Tags: java, android, ios, flutter, pdf

I'm trying to make an application to create a PDF. Using 3 libraries on `flutter`: `pdf 3.10.3`, `path_provider 2.0.15`, `open_document 1.0.6+2`. The code will be just below. The bottom line is that everything works fine on iOS, but it's different with android: when you click the button the app just crashes, and the console has this output:

```
D/EGL_emulation(32619): app_time_stats: avg=4177.76ms min=631.96ms max=7723.56ms 

    count=2
    D/DART/NATIVE(32619): onMethodCall openDocument
    E/AndroidRuntime(32619): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-4
    E/AndroidRuntime(32619): Process: com.example.testingv2, PID: 32619
    E/AndroidRuntime(32619): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Couldn't find meta-data for provider with authority com.example.testingv2.fileprovider
    E/AndroidRuntime(32619):    at androidx.core.content.FileProvider.getFileProviderPathsMetaData(FileProvider.java:664)
    E/AndroidRuntime(32619):    at androidx.core.content.FileProvider.parsePathStrategy(FileProvider.java:695)
    E/AndroidRuntime(32619):    at androidx.core.content.FileProvider.getPathStrategy(FileProvider.java:645)
    E/AndroidRuntime(32619):    at androidx.core.content.FileProvider.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:449)
    E/AndroidRuntime(32619):    at com.fsconceicao.open_document.OpenDocument.openDocument$open_document_debug(OpenDocument.kt:37)
    E/AndroidRuntime(32619):    at com.fsconceicao.open_document.OpenDocumentImpl.onMethodCall$lambda-5(OpenDocumentImpl.kt:55)
    E/AndroidRuntime(32619):    at com.fsconceicao.open_document.OpenDocumentImpl.$r8$lambda$dC68NxXnNWsal4uI2taad3gzBJ8(Unknown Source:0)
    E/AndroidRuntime(32619):    at com.fsconceicao.open_document.OpenDocumentImpl$$ExternalSyntheticLambda4.run(Unknown Source:6)
    E/AndroidRuntime(32619):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
    I/Process (32619): Sending signal. PID: 32619 SIG: 9
    Lost connection to device.
```

As I understood, all problems come from the ISP. I, according to the documentation from `open_document 1.0.6+2` did everything exactly as described there (just copied and pasted). In the folder `android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`.

Manifest code:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
        <application
            android:label="testingv2"
            android:name="${applicationName}"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
            <activity
                android:name=".MainActivity"
                android:exported="true"
                android:launchMode="singleTop"
                android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
                android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
                android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
                android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
                <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                     the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                     while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                     to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
                <meta-data
                  android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
                  android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
                  />
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
            <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
                 This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="flutterEmbedding"
                android:value="2" />
            <provider
                android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
                android:authorities="com.example.testingv2.fileprovider"
                android:exported="false"
                android:grantUriPermissions="true">
                <meta-data
                    android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                    android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
            </provider>
        </application>
    </manifest>
```

I created a folder and a file inside (`android/app/src/main/res/xml/provider_paths.xml`) and just threw in everything from the documentation without changing anything (maybe I should):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <paths>
       <external-path
         name="external_files"
         path="." />
     </paths>
```

Here is the application code itself:

`main.dart`:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:pdf/widgets.dart' as pw;
    import 'package:pdf/pdf.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/services.dart' show ByteData, rootBundle;
    import 'dart:io';
    import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
    import 'package:printing/printing.dart';
    
    import 'creat/create.dart';
    
    void main() => runApp(MyApp());
    
    class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
      final CreaterPdf service = CreaterPdf();
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
          home: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text('demka'),
            ),
            body: Center(
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  TextButton(
                    onPressed: () async {
                      final data = await service.generatePDF();
                      service.savePdfFile('fileName', data);
                    },
                    child: Text('demka'),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

`create.dart`:

```
import 'dart:io';
    import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
    import 'package:open_document/open_document.dart';
    import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
    import 'package:pdf/pdf.dart';
    import 'package:pdf/widgets.dart' as pw;
    
    class CreaterPdf {
      Future<Uint8List> generatePDF() async {
        final pdf = pw.Document(); 
        final ttf = await rootBundle
            .load("assets/fonts/Roboto-Bold.ttf"); 
        final font = pw.Font.ttf(ttf);
        final page = pw.Page(
          pageFormat: PdfPageFormat.a4,
          build: (pw.Context context) {
            return pw.Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: pw.CrossAxisAlignment.end,
              children: <pw.Widget>[
                pw.Text(
                  "Кому-то короче:",
                  style: pw.TextStyle(fontSize: 14, font: font),
                ),
                pw.Text('Пупкин Олег Букин',
                    style: pw.TextStyle(fontSize: 14, font: font)),
                pw.SizedBox(height: 50),
                pw.Center(
                    child: pw.Text("мир",
                        style: pw.TextStyle(fontSize: 30, font: font))),
                pw.SizedBox(height: 50),
                pw.Text("пока", style: pw.TextStyle(fontSize: 20, font: font)),
              ],
            );
          },
        );
        pdf.addPage(page); 
        final bytes = await pdf.save();
        final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
        final file = File("${directory.path}/example.pdf");
        await file.writeAsBytes(bytes);
        return pdf.save();
      }
    
      Future<void> savePdfFile(String fileName, Uint8List byteList) async {
        final output = await getTemporaryDirectory();
        var filePath = "${output.path}/$fileName.pdf";
        final file = File(filePath);
        await file.writeAsBytes(byteList);
        await OpenDocument.openDocument(filePath: filePath);
      }
    }
```

On iOS, when you press the button, it goes like this:
[when pressing a button on iOS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ytE4.png)

In `andriod studio`:

[android studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zGlAA.png)

The crash happens when I try to open a previously created pdf, but it does not find it and the crash follows (again, as I understand it). But how to solve it?

I changed the line in the manifest, but it didn't help. What I want to get: When I click on the button, as on iOS, the created pdf will open in the application (as shown in the screenshot), and then it would be simply possible to save or send (as on iOS) this PDF

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure just guessing may be this will help:

1. Open the provider_paths.xml file located at android/app/src/main/res/xml/provider_paths.xml.
2. Replace the existing content with the following code:

   ```
   <paths>
     <external-path
       name="external_files"
       path="." />
    <cache-path
       name="cache_files"
       path="." />
   </paths>
   ```
3. In your AndroidManifest.xml, update the android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS metadata value
   to use:

   @xml/provider_paths

   instead of:

   @xml/path_provider:
4. Update the savePdfFile method in your CreaterPdf class as follows:

   final output = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I did everything as you wrote, but got this: 
"E/AndroidRuntime( 5942): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains /data/data/com.example.testingv2/app_flutter/fileName.pdf
E/AndroidRuntime( 5942):  at androidx.core.content.FileProvider$SimplePathStrategy.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:825)
Lost connection to device.
Failed to send request: {"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":"33","method":"getMemoryUsage","params":{"isolateId":"isolates/2817579040777927"}}"